# the update function in my flutter app crashes the app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I work with Firestore in my flutter application. I programmed that you can create notes and edit them. If i call my update function in the creation of the note the app doesen't crash. If I call it afterwards the app crashes. I printed the error to the console and this was what i got:

> Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/matti/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.14.0/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:116:14
> path.isNotEmpty
> "a document path must be a non-empty string"

I printed the `documentId` right in front of it and got a valid documentId of my database.

If you need anything else I will gladly send it to you, but i don't know what else you would need.

This is my function:

```
 class FirebaseCloudStorageAngebote {
    final notesAngebote = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notesAngebote');
    
      
    
     Future<void> updateNoteAngebote({
        required String documentId,
        required String textJob,
        required String textAdresse,
        required String textBezahlung,
        required String textKontakt,
        required String textZeit,
        required String textStadt,
        required String textStadtviertel
      }) async {
        try {
          await notesAngebote.doc(documentId).update({
            textJobFieldName: textJob,
            textAdresseFieldName: textAdresse,
            textBezahlungFieldName: textBezahlung,
            textKontaktFieldName: textKontakt,
            textZeitFieldName: textZeit,
            textStadtviertelFieldName: textStadtviertel,
            textStadtFieldName: textStadt,
          });
        } catch (e) {
          throw CouldNotUpdateNoteException();
        }
      }
    
     
        
    
     
    
      static final FirebaseCloudStorageAngebote _shared =
          FirebaseCloudStorageAngebote._sharedInstance();
      FirebaseCloudStorageAngebote._sharedInstance();
      factory FirebaseCloudStorageAngebote() => _shared;
    }
```

This is where i call it:

```
  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty(String documentId) async {
    
    final textAdresse = "example";
    final textStadt = "example";
    final textStadtviertel = "example";
    final textZeit = "example";
    final textBezahlung = "example";
    final textKontakt = "example";
    final textJob = "example";
    if ( textAdresse.isNotEmpty && textJob.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNoteAngebote(
        documentId: documentId,
        textAdresse: textAdresse,
        textJob: textJob,
        textBezahlung: textBezahlung,
        textKontakt: textKontakt,
        textZeit: textZeit,
        textStadt: textStadt,
        textStadtviertel: textStadtviertel,
      );
    }
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: ()  {
              _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty(widget.documentId);
             Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NotesViewAngebote()),
                (route) => false,
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body:...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding **more** code is not the solution, but reproducing the problem in isolation typically is. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as right now I see no immediate calls to Firestore in the code you shared - so it's hard to say where you're going wrong.

Comment: The `documentId` is not the same as the document path, just like a file name is not the full path of the file. Check that `notesAngebote` is referring to the right path of the Firestore collection

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: I havent solved the issue

Comment: I edited the code, i hope, that now it is easier for you.